# How do you transfer at Doha airport?

Tags: transit, doh

According to [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MrF0LZICLxs), when transiting at Doha Airport, you'll get a colour code on your boarding pass wallet: yellow for regular transfer in the main building, yellow with an orange edge for short Transfer in the main building, and green for transfer in the satellite building. There are then separate buses and bus stops depending on your colour.

One comment, however, states:

> This video was made when the overcrowded old airport was in use. The new Hamad International Airport is open now, which works like any other airport - there are no special transfer procedures.

So, how does transfer at Doha **currently** work, with all possible scenarios combined where you have your onward boarding pass and want to get to your next gate directly?

If the colour system is still in place, how are you assigned a colour if checking in online and thus not going to a check-in desk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That video is almost 5 years old. OTHH opened 2½+ years ago. For transfers [there](http://dohahamadairport.com/airport-guide/at-the-airport/transfers):

> Upon exiting your aircraft please go directly to our Transfers hall.

Or

> **Short connections**
>
> If your onward flight is departing in less than 45 minutes after your arrival at Hamad International Airport, then we can speed you through transfer formalities to help you reach your boarding gate on time. Please alert our ground staff as soon as you exit your aircraft and walk onto the aerobridge, or as you board the passenger bus.