# Transiting Doha Hamad International Airport

Tags: transit, short-connections, doh

Can you walk from terminal 1C to terminal 2 at Doha's Hamad International Airport? How long will it take? I only have one hour between flights.

Comment: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/85311/how-do-you-transfer-at-doha-airport